# mask public IP addresses from any command output (for diagnostic)

Tags: sed, busybox, sh, replace, mask

I'm writing a script to extract information from BusyBox v1.25.1/Linux 2.6.36/router where the user can simply run the script and copy/paste the output into a submission form to request support. The script it's essentially a list of commands like `route`, `ifconfig`, etc. Because of the busybox implication I'm restricted to /bin/sh.

I'm trying to find a smart way to automatically mask all the public IP addresses only from the output. Replace the full IP would be already good but if it's possible I would be looking for a command to pipe at the end of each command (even an internal function) to simply replace let's say the first two octects e.g.
`80.80.80.80`
with
`XX.XX.80.80`

A nice to have feature would be to replace the same number of digits to retain formatting where possible. e.g.

`8.8.8.8=X.X.X.X
80.80.8.8=XX.XX.X.X
180.180.80.8=XXX.XXX.XX.X`

practical example:

`root@router:/proc# route | filtering-goes-here
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
XX.XX.168.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 vlan2
172.16.9.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br1
10.10.9.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
10.114.126.0    *               255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 tun11
XX.XX.168.0     *               255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 vlan2
10.10.0.0       *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 tinc
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
default         cpc86269        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vlan2`

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does a `sed` script like this work for you?

```
$ cat filter.sed
s|\([0-9]\+\.\)\([0-9]\+\.\)\([0-9]\+\.\)\([0-9]\+\)|___\1___\2___\3___\4|g
s|___[0-9]|___X|g
s|___X[0-9]|___XX|g
s|___XX[0-9]|___XXX|g
s|___||g
```

Here is an example run,

```
$ echo "111.22.3.44" | sed -f filter.sed
XXX.XX.X.XX
```

This is going to convert all IP addresses of the form `a.b.c.d` into equivalent width `x.x.x.x` pattern. If you need to skip some IP addresses those would need exclusion rules in the script.

If the `___` pattern is part of your possible output in the context used here, you would need to change to a different 'context' that is not possible in the input to the script.

**Update: for public IP masking**
Try this `sed` script replacement to the above basic one.

```
s|\([0-9]\+\)\.\([0-9]\+\)\.\([0-9]\+\)\.\([0-9]\+\)|__#\1.\2.\3.\4|g
s|#0\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|0\1|g
s|#10\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|10\1|g
s|#127\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|127\1|g
s|#255\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|255\1|g
s|#\(22[4-9]\)\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|\1\2|g
s|#\(23[0-8]\)\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|\1\2|g
s|#169\.254\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|169.254\1|g
s|#192\.168\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|192.168\1|g
s|#\(172\.1[6789]\)\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|\1\2|g
s|#\(172\.2[0-9]\)\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|\1\2|g
s|#\(172\.3[01]\)\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|\1\2|g
s|__#\([0-9]\+\.\)\([0-9]\+\.\)\([0-9]\+\.\)\([0-9]\+\)|___\1___\2___\3___\4|g
s|___[0-9]|___X|g
s|___X[0-9]|___XX|g
s|___XX[0-9]|___XXX|g
s|___||g
s|__||g
```

Note: This will also `x`-out the netmasks with one exception. I've not added `240.0.0.0` to the list.

**Update2: If you want to just mask the first IP-address on each line**
This is for a `route` output case where the first column is IP addresses.
Replace the first line in the updated `sed` script with,

```
s|^\(\s*\)\([0-9]\+\)\.\([0-9]\+\)\.\([0-9]\+\)\.\([0-9]\+\)|\1__#\2.\3.\4.\5|g
```

---

**On OPs suggestion, leaving also the mask-for-private-IPs script here**

```
# Modified version that limits to first IP on each line prefixed with whitespace.
s|^\(\s*\)\([0-9]\+\)\.\([0-9]\+\)\.\([0-9]\+\)\.\([0-9]\+\)|\1___#\2.\3.\4.\5|g
# Basic version that operates on all IP strings in the input.
#s|\([0-9]\+\)\.\([0-9]\+\)\.\([0-9]\+\)\.\([0-9]\+\)|___#\1.\2.\3.\4|g
#
s|\([0-9]\+\)\.\([0-9]\+\)\.\([0-9]\+\)\.\([0-9]\+\)|___#\1.\2.\3.\4|g
s|___#0\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|___0\1|g
s|___#10\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|___10\1|g
s|___#127\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|___127\1|g
s|___#255\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|___255\1|g
s|___#224\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|___224\1|g
s|___#\(22[4-9]\)\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|___\1\2|g
s|___#\(23[0-8]\)\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|___\1\2|g
s|___#169\.254\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|___169.254\1|g
s|___#192\.168\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|___192.168\1|g
s|___#\(172\.1[6789]\)\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|___\1\2|g
s|___#\(172\.2[0-9]\)\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|___\1\2|g
s|___#\(172\.3[01]\)\(\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)|___\1\2|g
s|___\([0-9]\+\.\)\([0-9]\+\.\)\([0-9]\+\.\)\([0-9]\+\)|___\1___\2___\3___\4|g
s|___[0-9]|___X|g
s|___X[0-9]|___XX|g
s|___XX[0-9]|___XXX|g
s|___#||g
s|___||g
```

Comment: I was trying to restrict the masking to public IP addresses only.

Comment: I've updated with a more detailed `sed` version in my answer. If you don't want the `netmask` column to be 'masked-out' you can tweak the first line of the script to make the IP address selection more biased. I am adding one more update for that now.

Comment: This is impressive :-o
The only thing is: it is applying the mask to private IPs and not public as far as I can tell? e.g.  my public router  IP  is left exposed, so the logic should be reversed, also no need to mask netmasks...

Comment: `:-)` My bad! I was trying out the inverse since it was easier to check and lost-track of that twist. Try the fixed version now.

Comment: wow spot on !!!

Comment: P.S. I would leave here documented even your prev version as somebody  might want to filter private IPs only.

Comment: Done. Have also sneaked in a fix for the Multicast IPs which I overlooked earlier.

Comment: Since you're so fast... :-D
I'm wondering if it's possible to apply the masking  filters you've created (public range) to the first two octects only? so `81.82.83.84` would be masked `XX.XX.83.84`

Sometimes you do want to know the ending IP and knowing at least  the last two octects can really  help without compromising the privacy.

Thanks!!

Comment: Sure. Try commenting out the last two lines with `X` in the sed script.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the last suggestion. Are you saying to quote these two lines?
`s|___X[0-9]|___XX|g`
and
`s|___XX[0-9]|___XXX|g`
?

Comment: Never mind just found it:

`s|___\([0-9]\+\.\)\([0-9]\+\.\)\([0-9]\+\.\)\([0-9]\+\)|___\1___\2___\3___\4|g`

into

`s|__#\([0-9]\+\.\)\([0-9]\+\)|___\1___\2|g`

Thanks!!!!

Comment: You are on the right track.  
My cursory suggestion was incorrect (it would just change the numbers partly).  
However, I'll suggest you edit your solution into this form: `s|__#\([0-9]\+\.\)\([0-9]\+\.\)\([0-9]\+\.\)\([0-9]\+\)|___\1___\2\3\4|g`.  
That way you won't mask numbers like `123.45` which are not IP addresses.

Comment: The solution you provided is perfect thank you!!!
I have now opened a second request, pretty much identical but to mask FQDNs:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1007097/mask-fqdns-from-any-command-output-for-diagnostic